# encrypt external disk does not work

Tags: encryption, luks

Iam following this tutorial to encrypt an external disk: https://miguelmenendez.pro/en/articles/encrypt-usb-storage-device-linux-unified-key-setup-luks.html

But in step 6, I get after typing `cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdc1` and `YES` this error:

```
Device /dev/sdb1 doesn't exist or access denied.
```

What did I do wrong? Actually, nothing changed with the external Disk. It has still the label of the company (Elements) and there are still all the same files available (starting files of the company). Shouldnt that all be gone after deleting partition and making a new one?

Yes, I **did** type `w` after making the changes in fdisk

Yes, my disk is on `/dev/sdb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

command `cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdc1` must be used with sudo